# How to position element at build

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Ok so I have an horizontal listView and I am trying to add a transform on each listview item depending on where it is from the horizontal center of the screen.

Now the issue is that it seems impossible for me to know the position of elements at initial builds as I can't get values of attached GlobalKey bounds.

trying to achieve something close to this

[image]

How can I get position of that listView elements or work around this?

Answer (score 0):

use this pack: https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector

if visiblePercentage = 100% => element isShowing

```
VisibilityDetector(
    key: Key('my-widget-key'),
    onVisibilityChanged: (visibilityInfo) {
      var visiblePercentage = visibilityInfo.visibleFraction * 100;
      debugPrint(
          'Widget ${visibilityInfo.key} is ${visiblePercentage}% visible');
    },
    child: someOtherWidget,
  );
```

Comment: good hack as I am forcing a setState `onVisibilityChanged` but ofcourse there is lag